# XPath to match multiple nodes depending on siblings child value

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to select a file with Xpath . If the Xpath finds a matching value in:

(`//Party/PartyIdentification/ID[text()="6655779999"]`) OR
(`//Party/PartyTaxScheme/CompanyID[text()="US6655779999"]` AND `TaxScheme/ID = DEY`) OR
(`//Party/PartyTaxScheme/CompanyID[text()="US6655779999"]` AND `TaxScheme/ID = BSY`)

it selects the right file.

I started off using: `//BuyerParty/Party/PartyIdentification/ID[text()="6655779999"]` and it works perfect!

But I can't figure out how to extend the xpath to also check the other two paths with their DEY and BSY conditions. I spend weeks so far and turned the forum inside out to find an answer, but with no luck.

The reson for this OR condition is that one, two or all three of the elements might exist in the xml file. I never know which one prior. I need to get at least one match of the three matching criteria above to be sure to select the right file.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
<ROOT>
<BuyerParty>
    <Party>
        <PartyIdentification>
            <ID>6655779999</ID>
        </PartyIdentification>
        <PartyName>
            <Name>Charly</Name>
        </PartyName>
        <Address>
            <StreetName>El Cajon Boulevard</StreetName>
            <CityName>San Diego</CityName>
            <PostalZone>92104</PostalZone>
            <Country>
                <IdentificationCode>US</IdentificationCode>
            </Country>
        </Address>
        <PartyTaxScheme>
            <CompanyID>US11432112341</CompanyID>
            <TaxScheme>
                <ID>DEY</ID>
            </TaxScheme>
        </PartyTaxScheme>
        <PartyTaxScheme>
            <CompanyID>US1143211234</CompanyID>
            <TaxScheme>
                <ID>BSY</ID>
            </TaxScheme>
        </PartyTaxScheme>
        <Contact>
            <Telephone>555-5555555</Telephone>
        </Contact>
    </Party>
</BuyerParty>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `|` (or) selector

```
//Party/PartyIdentification/ID[text()="6655779999"]|//Party/PartyTaxScheme/CompanyID[following-sibling::TaxScheme/ID = 'DEY' or following-sibling::TaxScheme/ID = 'BSY'][text()="US11432112341"]
```

Comment: Looks very promising! But what if CompanyID have different matching criteria for TaxScheme/ID = 'DEY' and TaxScheme/ID = 'BSY'? Let's say  US11432112341 for DEY and US123 for BSY